# Jquery DateTimePicker not working with asp.net master page and content page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have been struggling to get the datetime picker working with Asp.net 4.0. I have added the jquery-1.5.2.min.js and jquery-datepicker.js inside the scripts folder. I'm getting error message

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method
```

inside jquery-1.5.2.min.js .

I went through the similar questions posted in stackoverflow, but still not able to resolve the answer. I'm sure that the script path is not getting resolved properly. I tried different combinations adding the script tag in Master and also content page.It still did not work. I also tried ResolveUrl in content page, it still failed.

Updated code - still gives error for me.
           ' type="text/javascript">
             ' type="text/javascript">
               '                  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

```
       $(document).ready(function ()
        {
           $("#<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>").datepicker(); 
        });     

         </script>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server"> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.5.2.min.js" ></script> 
         <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-datepicker.js" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function () 
       {

     $(function () {
         $("#<%=txtDateFrom.ClientID %>").datepicker();             
     });

 }); /*----------------------End of Document Ready----------------------------*/
</script>
```

Can someone who has worked with Master and content pages and have included jquery datetime picker in the content page help me please?

Comment: did you use firebug or dev tools in chrome to check what path it's looking at and if the js files are loading? Even in FF if you just "View Source" you can click the src links to make sure that the page is actually loading your files

Comment: also if your page is in `.com/foo/bar/page.aspx` then your script points to `.com/foo/jquer...`

Comment: This is probably unrelated, but I suggest you update jQuery to 1.7.2 via NuGet. Also referencing your scripts like this is better: `<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>`  
I don't see a reference to a DateTimePicker, but if you need a good one use [this](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/)

Comment: @ShahinDohan the OP doesn't look he's using razor views (or mvc for that matter) so the `@Url` wouldn't work for him (I think). While I've used the timepicker you linked to it required `jquery ui` which he's also not referencing.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is a specific reason why you can't use a Repository like Google's or jQuery, I would suggest you add the jQuery library from one.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

Edit: Seems like you have this in the body of the page. Try adding it to the Header (maybe Content1 contentplaceholder?)

Good luck!

EDIT: I have now created a folder called Course, and a page called Course.aspx and this works for me:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
        CodeFile="Course.aspx.cs" Inherits="Course_Course" %>

        <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="Server">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
            <script src='=<%Response.Write(Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker.js")); %>' type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src='<%Response.Write(Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.js"));%>' type="text/javascript"></script>
            <link href='<%Response.Write(Page.ResolveUrl("~/Styles/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.css")); %>' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>").datepicker();
                });
            </script>
        </asp:Content>
        <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="Server">
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </asp:Content>
```

Good luck!

Comment: Hi Hanlet, I tried adding it to the Header and I still get the error. This is making me suffer..

Comment: Hanlet, Even after adding the src to point Google's repository, I still get the error..Do you have a similar link for datetime picker as well??

Comment: I do not. Let me set up the same as you and see why you are getting that error and I will get back to you.

Comment: Thanks Hanlet. Just to let you know the folder structure of mine. Its a VS2010, Asp.net website. It has a master page.I have a folder name course inside I have a file name course.aspx where I'm trying to set the datetime picker. The jquery files reside under Scripts folder. The stylesheet for datetime picker is in <link href="Styles/JqDatePicker/redmond/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: I have the TextBox inside the MasterPage. Is that how you have it? I have updated the code, check it out.

Comment: No I have the textbox inside the content page.

Comment: Do I need to have the files jquery.ui.datepicker.js and jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.js inside scripts folder? If so where would I download this file.

Comment: You can have the files wherever you wish as long as you have the right path in the ResolveUrl function. The custom.min.js file is the jqueryui core file I got for downloading just the calendarpicker. I think it has a different name if you download the entire thing.

Comment: Hanlet, I tried the above code and I still get the same error. I'm not sure what am i missing here. I also tried it in a new asp.net wesbsite and I got the same error. Here are the steps I did. Created a new Vs2010 asp.net website. Added a new folder course and file course.aspx . Inside scripts folder added jquery-1.5.2.min.js and jquery-datepicker.js files. And inside styles added a folder JqDatePicker .Inside folder JqDatePicker added another folder redmond and inside redmond added another folder images which has some image files and rdemond folder also has datepicker.css file.

Comment: When I debug Im getting error in jquery-1.5.2.min.js file in the below line. It says object does not support this property or method. It gives error in the first finally block,finally{b=[d,f],c=0}}return this} . Im not sure whats going on here..cant find the exact problem..help please..

Comment: Send me an email to hanlet.escano@gmail.com and I will send you a working example. This, however, should have worked just fine for you.